# MySQL update query makes new table row instead of updating table row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When trying to make an edit page for a table in PHP, I'm running into a problem on the edit.php page where when I click edit table row button, it brings me to the correct page obviously (edit.php), and then when I enter in the edited details and submit it, it makes a whole new table row entry instead of update the one I had selected for it to update.

I have checked to make sure the id is set correctly to the correct table row in the database and it is. I have no idea why it is doing this. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
<?php require("manage_post.php"); ?>
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userName'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?> 

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("cad", $con) 
    or die('Could not select database'); 

$query="SELECT `town`, `location`, `incident_type`, `time_date`, `admin`, `id` 
FROM `cad` 
WHERE `id` = 
$_GET[id]"; 

$result=mysql_query($query) 
  or die(mysql_error()); 

while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) )
{
    echo '<h1>Town name: ', htmlspecialchars($row['town']), '</td>';
}




$town=$row['town'] ;
$location= $row['location'] ;                   
$incident_type=$row['incident_type'] ;


if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $incident_type = $_POST['incident_type'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE cad SET town ='{$town}', location ='{$location}',
         incident_type ='{$incident_type}' WHERE `id` = $_GET[id]") or die(mysql_error()); 

    echo "Saved! Redirecting back to the home page.";

}
mysql_close($con);

    $id=$_GET['id']; 
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Incident</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    echo "<h1>You are editing incident number # $id</h1>";
?>
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Town</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="town" value="<?php echo $town; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Incident Type</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="incident_type" value="<?php echo $incident_type; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo` your query and post it too

Comment: @Uchiha, which query do you want me to echo?

Comment: This one? `mysql_query("UPDATE cad SET town ='{$town}', location ='{$location}',
         incident_type ='{$incident_type}' WHERE ``id` `= $_GET[id]") or die(mysql_error());  `

Answer (score 0):

You have to use query like below

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cad SET town ='{$town}', location ='{$location}',
     incident_type ='{$incident_type}' WHERE `id` = {$_GET['id']}") or die(mysql_error()); ;
```

Comment: is your $_GET['id'] has some value? try to print the query before running the query

Comment: I have. When printed on the page, the id is the correct one like it should be.

Comment: Can you do an echo "UPDATE cad SET town ='{$town}', location ='{$location}',
     incident_type ='{$incident_type}' WHERE `id` = {$_GET['id']}" and show me the query what you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

Add new hidden key to post

```
<input type="hidden" name="savedid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" />
```

And in the update sql

```
$town = $_POST['town'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$incident_type = $_POST['incident_type'];
$savedid = $_POST['savedid'];
mysql_query("UPDATE cad SET town ='{$town}', location ='{$location}',
     incident_type ='{$incident_type}' WHERE `id` = $savedid") or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "Saved! Redirecting back to the home page.";
```

and you should filter your vars if security concerns you consider using intval for ids

Comment: I forgot to mention, my input boxes on my edit page have always been blank (not prefilled with the already submitted info). like this: http://i.imgur.com/WORB9mS.png.

Comment: Put $town and others vars inside while and change $_GET[id] to $id in the first select sql and add $id = $_GET['id'] at start of the file and make sure your url request not  uppercase "ID=20"